# Which one is the better way to handle controllers in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Which one is the better way to handle controllers in angular js.

```
   .when('/start', {
        templateUrl: 'views/start.html',
        controller: 'StartCtrl',
        resolve: {
            loggedin: verifyLoggedin;
        }
    });
```

or

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head></head>
<body ng-controller="StartCtrl"></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, you can't compare controller in this both way, because this both are having a different scenario, first one is for routing, you must have to mention controller at there with dissociated view.

About second one that you are linking up your controller with particular view, so both case are different.

Let me know if i am wrong or might be some other way you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For routing the first option is the better way to handle the controller.

Take a look at [John Papa's angular 1 style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) for better practices on angular.